# GTK+3 custom drawing area

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I am new to GTK+3 and I want to create a custom drawing widget (maybe a grid). I need to be able to drag and drop logic objects on it for my logic gate simulator. How can this be done? The Drawing Area should be beside the menu containing logic objects.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably recommend you use a [GtkDrawingArea](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkDrawingArea.html) inside a [GtkScrolledWindow](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkScrolledWindow.html). All drawing will have to be custom using [Cairo](https://www.cairo.org). Draw a grid, then handle arranging your logic objects manually. You could use one of the [GtkToolItem](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkToolItem.html#gtk-tool-item-set-visible-vertical) widgets for your top or side box of objects.

It's an ambitious project for the first time, but very similar to my first major project. It uses a very similar GtkDrawingArea idea. It's in Perl, and is [here on GitHub](https://github.com/oldtechaa/SeekMIDI). If you can decipher Perl, it might provide you some ideas for how a custom widget can be done.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion your requirements seem to be more tailored to a canvas. Project Ridley includes [a selection](https://wiki.gnome.org/Attic/ProjectRidley/CanvasOverview) of canvases candidate to be included in GTK+. Not sure this is still relevant now, but that selection is a good.

Comment: I've found GooCanvas to be quite decent.